# JDBC DatabaseMetaData gives empty columns for UTF-8 characters tablename

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, unicode

I am executing the following code snippet:

```
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
            java.util.Properties properties = new java.util.Properties();
            properties.put("user", "root");
            properties.put("password", "root");
            properties.put("characterEncoding","UTF-8");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, properties);
            DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = conn.getMetaData();
            String tableName = "北美";

            ResultSet rs = databaseMetaData.getColumns(null, "test", tableName, "%");
```

This gives no columns for a tablename which is in a language other than English. However, it gives proper column metadata for English tablenames.

Connection: MySQL using mysql-connector-java-5.1.16-bin.jar
The schema is proper and I am able to use this connection/column metadata for any normal English tablename

What is wrong that it is not working with other unicode characters?

Comment: you have to use in the place of 北美 unicode format like this for indian rupee C/C++/Java source code "\u20B9"

Comment: Any clue how to convert this value? (As it is generated at runtime)

Comment: http://www.snible.org/java2/uni2java.html

Comment: yes unicode working in run time no problem but may i know what is that symbol

Comment: Squirrel also cannot read the column metadata from a table with that name. Quoting does also not help. You could file a bug report for the mysql JDBC driver.

Comment: Are you connecting to the database with utf8?

Comment: The connection properties and URL both have UTF-8 specified. Any other place I need to specify "UTF-8"